# Ask a range of questions and store in variables [Discord.PY]

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to create a range of questions to ask someone in the same command but I wanna store each answer in it's own variable.

I just don't know how to do it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You really want a collection to store them in, lets say you managed to make these multiple variables, how would you actually use them?

Comment: @Sayse - I am just re-learning discord.py and would like to know it for any future events.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```py
@client.command()
async def questions(ctx):

        questions = [
            "question 1?",
            "question 2?"
        ]

        answers = []

        for i in questions:
                await ctx.send(i)

                try:

                      msg = await client.wait_for('message', timeout=30.0, check=check)
                
                except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                        await ctx.send("Setup timed out, please be quicker next time!")
                        return
                else:
                        answers.append(msg.content)

        embed = discord.Embed(title='Results', description=answers, colour=discord.Color.blue())

        message = await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

I don't think it's possible for python to create a variable by itself, though I may be wrong. Here's a way to ask and store questions using discord.py

If I answered incorrectly or didn't meet the points of your question, I'm really sorry.